# Google Protobuf dependency collision

Tags: go, dependencies, protocol-buffers, dependency-management, grpc

I am working on a Golang library that leverages Google [Protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf). It does so by using code auto-generated by protoc-gen-go, the compiler plugin. I am using [Dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) for dependency management. 
The generated code exports the `InstanceStatusUpdate` struct, for which the field `Timestamp` is of the type `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp.Timestamp`:

```
type InstanceStatusUpdate struct {
    EvaluationId  string
    VariationId   string
    AttemptNumber int32
    Timestamp     *google_protobuf.Timestamp
    Stage         string
    Metadata      string
    JobId         string
}
```

The problem I have is that writing library code to populate the Timestamp field triggers a redundant auto-importing of `"github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"`, since that is where the type that needs to be assigned to Timestamp lives. This redundancy causes this error:

> cannot use timestamp (type
>   *"my_path/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp".Timestamp)
>   as type *"github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp".Timestamp in
>   field value

Any ideas?

library structure (only one vendor folder):

```
code_root
|
 -lib
|  |
|   -go-statuses
 -my_package /*Contains code that refers to the auto-generated code in 
   |          go-statuses*/
   |
    -vendor
```

Comment: The problem here is that you have two copies of the github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes package. Don't do that. And it's not malpractice to export your own types. Virtually *every* package does that and it is what makes them useful. You could have also said it's wrong that the time package exports Time, and should instead only accept and return ints.

Comment: Hey Peter, I am not sure I understand the answer. I am aware that there are two copies and that creates the issue - it is the way around it that I don't understand: The generated code exposes Timestamp and I need to populate it. How do I write code to do that without another copy of the dependency being created and causing the confusion between my library's copy and the one the auto-generated code depends on?

Comment: It's hard to tell. It looks like you may have nested vendor directories. Add your directory layout to the question, starting at GOPATH and including all subdirectories that lead to those called ptypes.

Comment: Move the vendor directory to the project root. Otherwise go-statuses sees a different ptypes package than my_package.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: Peter this seems to have done the trick!